# Round up BigDecimal to Integer value

Tags: java, math, rounding, bigdecimal

I have a BigDecimal which value is 450.90, I want to round up to next hole integer value, and then print the Integer value without any decimal points, like this;

Val: 450.90 -> Rounded: 451.00 -> Output: 451

Val: 100.00001 -> Rounded: 101.00000 Output: 101

Checked some solutions but I'm not getting the expected result, heres my code;

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(450.90);
value.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); //Also tried with RoundingMode.UP
return value.intValue();
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are ignoring the setScale in your example

Comment: Do you mean like `(int) Math.ceil(450.90)` ?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

[`setScale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-int-) *returns* a new `BigDecimal` with the result, it doesn't change the instance you call it on. So assign the return value back to `value`:

```
value = value.setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP);
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/B5Xmu8)

I also changed it to `RoundingMode.UP` because you said you *always* wanted to round up. But depending on your needs, you might want `RoundingMode.CEILING` instead; it depends on what you want `-451.2` to become (`-452` [`UP`] or `-451` [`CEILING`]). See [`RoundingMode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) for more.

Comment: Great! this indeed solved my problem. I won't be working with negative numbers so RoundingMode.Up will work just fine! thanks

Comment: Do not work for me( I always get 451.0 but I need to get 451

Comment: @Black_Zerg: Then you must not be doing what's above; see the [live example](http://ideone.com/B5Xmu8).

Answer (score 6):

use:

```
value.setScale(0, RoundingMode.CEILING);
```

Answer (score 3):

From method description:

> Note that since BigDecimal objects are immutable, calls of setScale
>   method do not result in the original object being modified, contrary
>   to the usual convention of having methods named setX mutate field X.
>   Instead, setScale returns an object with the proper scale; the
>   returned object may or may not be newly allocated.

```
public void test() {
  BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(450.90);
  System.out.println(value.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)); // prints 451
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the returned value

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(450.90);
value = value.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); //Also tried with RoundingMode.UP
```

note that [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) is invariant

> Scaling/rounding operations (setScale and round) return a BigDecimal
>   whose value is approximately (or exactly) equal to that of the
>   operand, but whose scale or precision is the specified value; that is,
>   they increase or decrease the precision of the stored number with
>   minimal effect on its value.

Answer (score -1):

use the `Math.ceil()` function. The method ceil gives the smallest integer that is greater than or equal to the argument.

You can read up on it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_ceil.htm)